What are those (1) numbers under each character in my castle?
All my characters have this circled 1:

I don't know what this number means.
My chump became super chump, so it's not related to an upgrade.
He also died twice, so it's not related to the number of deaths.
Alchemist is level 2, so it's not related to a tier also.
Does it have any meaning?

For what I can see, that's the hero's current level in the dungeon. You can notice that the number below your hero increases each time you get this message:

Here is an image of the same circle at the beginning of the dungeon and  after the level-up:

That's why all your heroes show 1 when in the guild, that's the starting level.
It's worth noting that your enemies will also have that number, which is an useful information when choosing who to battle.

That's exactly what the number is. I just witnessed the number changing after the level-up.
